# OWA and shared calendars

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

Can a user create and manage shared calendars exclusively from Outlook Web Access?

EDIT: We're working with Exchange 2010 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no simple way to do this.  You *can* manage other users' calendars by simply browsing to http://your_mail_server/Exchange/username/calendar/ after logging into OWA, but as far as managing a calendar not directly assigned to a user that is shared... I'm completely unsure.  Exchange 2010 actually has this functionality built-into OWA, and you can find the "open shared calendar" under the share-button.

This functionality is also somewhat exchange-version specific:

Exchange 2003: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821900

Exchange 2007: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb936726(EXCHG.80).aspx